# Wildcard match on phony targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a GNU Makefile, if I use `*` in a prerequisite or `$(wildcard)` in an assignment it will use shell expansion to find matching files.

Is there a way to do the equivalent for phony targets? For example:

```
.PHONY: compile-1 compile-2
compile-all: compile-*
```

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20550105/476716) but I don't want to have to manually list the targets as in `AVAILABLE_MODELS`.

"No, you have to list them" is an acceptable answer.

Comment: In the general case, you might want to enumerate all the targets. This is unfortunately not entirely trivial. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219255/how-do-you-get-the-list-of-targets-in-a-makefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to quite list them. You can compute them from their differences,
if that's sufficiently different:-

```
compiles := $(patsubst %,compile-%,1 2)

PHONY: $(compiles)

compile-all: $(compiles)
```

See [8.2 Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)

However, if `compile-N` is a phony target for some compilation you ought not to
have a phony target for that at all. Compilation makes real files, and they're
the targets, no need for phony ones.

On the other hand, `compile-all` clearly *should* to be a phony target.

Comment: `compile-N` are not real files

Comment: @OrangeDog. I appreciate that, but suspected that these each of these recipes *makes* a real file or files that would routinely be made without phony targets. Just a hunch, of course.

Comment: In my case, I use makefile targets to run some other commands instead of creating shortcuts somewhere else.